# bash to replace ${} placeholder for attachment

Tags: linux, bash, sed, mime, postfix-mta

I've been trying use `MIME-multipart` encoding to send both a plain text and an `HTML` version of the message using `postfix`.

I've created a temp-email.txt in tmp directory with the following contents:

```
From:Sender <xxxx@xxxx.com>
To:Recipient <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Subject: Result
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MixedBoundaryString"

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="AlternativeBoundaryString"

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Result

${detail}

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <head>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
      <p>${detail}</p>
  </body>
</html>
--AlternativeBoundaryString--
--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="${filename}"

${attachment}

--MixedBoundaryString--
```

And I've a bash script that replace `${}` placeholders in `temp-email.txt`.

Following is part of my bash script:

```
ATTACHMENT=$(base64 /tmp/result.txt)
EMAIL="/report/result.txt"

sed -e "s/\${result}/$1/" \
    -e "s/\${attachment}/$ATTACHMENT/" \
    -e "s/\${filename}/$FILENAME/" temp-email > $EMAIL
```

My problem here is I got the following error when replacing the ${attachment}

```
sed: -e expression #2, char 92: unterminated `s' command
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the value of `FILENAME` variable? and `$1`, last but not least I can't find `${result}` in your template

Comment: $1 is just a string, something like "Verification OK", FILENAME="test", the sed command without attachment does work, the error only when I try to replace the ${attachment} placeholder

Comment: Let me know if this works for you! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command on a file long enough

```
$ base64 /tmp/result.txt
```

it will produce an output like this:

```
PEhpdD4KICAgPEhpdF9udW0+MTwvSGl0X251bT4KICAgPEhpdF9pZD5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8
L0hpdF9pZD4KICAgPEhpdF9kZWY+Z25sfFY0VTBMNXwgVW5jaGFyYWN0ZXJpemVkIHByb3RlaW4g
W0hvbW8gc2FwaWVuXSBPWD0zOTMzMDUgR049Q0lDTEVfdjEwMDA4MTM2bWcgUEU9NCBTVj0xPC9I
aXRfZGVmPgogICA8SGl0X2FjY2Vzc2lvbj5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8L0hpdF9hY2Nlc3Npb24+
CiAgIDxIaXRfbGVuPjM4ODwvSGl0X2xlbj4KPC9IaXQ+Cg==
```

This output contains `EOL` characters that will **break** your command:

```
 -e "s/\${attachment}/PEhpdD4KICAgPEhpdF9udW0+MTwvSGl0X251bT4KICAgPEhpdF9pZD5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8
L0hpdF9pZD4KICAgPEhpdF9kZWY+Z25sfFY0VTBMNXwgVW5jaGFyYWN0ZXJpemVkIHByb3RlaW4g
W0hvbW8gc2FwaWVuXSBPWD0zOTMzMDUgR049Q0lDTEVfdjEwMDA4MTM2bWcgUEU9NCBTVj0xPC9I
aXRfZGVmPgogICA8SGl0X2FjY2Vzc2lvbj5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8L0hpdF9hY2Nlc3Npb24+
CiAgIDxIaXRfbGVuPjM4ODwvSGl0X2xlbj4KPC9IaXQ+Cg==/"
```

and give the error:

```
sed: -e expression #2, char 92: unterminated `s' command
```

because the end of the `s` command is not on the same line.

**How to solve it:**

Just remove the `\n` before passing it to `sed` by using a command like `tr -d'\n'` this will have no impact on the base64 decoding

example:

```
$ cat /tmp/result.txt 
<Hit>
   <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
   <Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
   <Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein [Homo sapien] OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
   <Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
   <Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
</Hit>
```

use

```
base64 /tmp/result.txt  | tr -d '\n'
```

if you decode it again:

```
$ base64 /tmp/result.txt | tr -d '\n' | base64 --decode
<Hit>
   <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
   <Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
   <Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein [Homo sapien] OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
   <Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
   <Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
</Hit>
```

**TEST:**

```
$ sed "s/\${attachment}/$(base64 /tmpt/result.txt| tr -d '\n')/" email_template 
From:Sender <xxxx@xxxx.com>
To:Recipient <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Subject: Result
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="MixedBoundaryString"

--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="AlternativeBoundaryString"

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Result

${detail}

--AlternativeBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <head>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
      <p>${detail}</p>
  </body>
</html>
--AlternativeBoundaryString--
--MixedBoundaryString
Content-Type: text/plain
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="${filename}"

PEhpdD4KICAgPEhpdF9udW0+MTwvSGl0X251bT4KICAgPEhpdF9pZD5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8L0hpdF9pZD4KICAgPEhpdF9kZWY+Z25sfFY0VTBMNXwgVW5jaGFyYWN0ZXJpemVkIHByb3RlaW4gW0hvbW8gc2FwaWVuXSBPWD0zOTMzMDUgR049Q0lDTEVfdjEwMDA4MTM2bWcgUEU9NCBTVj0xPC9IaXRfZGVmPgogICA8SGl0X2FjY2Vzc2lvbj5UUjpWNFUwTDVfOVJPU0k8L0hpdF9hY2Nlc3Npb24+CiAgIDxIaXRfbGVuPjM4ODwvSGl0X2xlbj4KPC9IaXQ+Cg==

--MixedBoundaryString--
```

Comment: It is working, thanks man, and thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: @Allan good solution, I will up vote, did you happen to see mine ?

Comment: Removing line breaks is against recommendations for `base64` and will wreck the message on many servers if the `base64` is longer than approx 1,000 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, you can use  envsubst which required gettext package. Note: what you are doing is similar to twig.

Example: 3 variables set

```
#!/bin/bash
#  sudo yum install gettext
detail="DETAIL"
filename="FILENAME"
attach=$(base64 /tmp/result.txt)
email="/report/result.txt"

export detail='somevalue' filename='someothervalue' attachment="$(echo $attach)"
MYVARS='$detail:$filename:$result:$attachment'

envsubst "$MYVARS" < temp-email > $email
```

Comment: nice solution as well :)